# Custom animation on hover

Tags: vue.js, web, animation, tailwind-css, css-animations

This is on the landing page of a VueJS project.  I personally don't know a lot about custom animations but I want this image:

[no_hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpNy0.png)

To be this image on hover.

[hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nrhP.png)

How can I achieve this?  If it matters this is a VueJs project with Tailwind.

I tried looking through the built in animation documentation in Vue and Tailwind but nothing immediately stood out to me to fix this issue.

I tried making a new asset that looks like the 'hover' version and then on hover show the hover asset but it was never smooth. The hover asset would show up smaller and in a slightly different location.  I feel like that approach may work but it felt 'hacky'.  I just feel like there should be a better way?